# Is it possible to navigate from feature file to step definition in VSCode

Tags: ruby, cucumber, visual-studio-code, gherkin

I am primarily using RubyMine for Cucumber/Ruby, and now, I'm getting my hands on VSCode, with which I'm able to run and debug test cases.

I can't find a way to navigate from feature to step definition. I tried searching for extensions and *cucumber-step-mapper* doesn't help.

Is there any config which enables navigation from feature to step definition?

Comment: You can by default with Webstorm. Would love to know if this is possible with Vs Code

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can install [**Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete) extension from the VSCode Marketplace:

After install is finished, reload VSCode.
Now in order to make it work for Ruby, you need to:

- Press `Ctrl + ,` to open *User Settings*
- Scroll down to *Cucumber Auto Complete*
- On the right side you need to modify these settings (you can find 2 examples of how to do this on the extension page). In my case, I added the following:

  ```
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "features/step_definitions/*.rb"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*feature"
  ```
- Reload *VSCode*
- Open a `.feature` file and right click any step, you should have ***Go To Definition*** and ***Peek Definition*** working.

Hope you get it working!

Comment: Do you see the warning `[cucumberautocomplete] was unable to find step for ...` while hovering over a step in the feature files? If that is the case, then I think the path must be specified in a different way.

Comment: The above did not work for me. I have [cucumberautocomplete] was unable to find step for ... error on every line. I confirmed the folders are correct.

Comment: sort of partially works for me - some step definitions correctly navigated to - others not ... :-/

Comment: I have many steps all over the place in my test folder, so would recommend using something like `"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "test/**/*.steps.ts"
    ]` to include all step files.

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped a lot!

Comment: Had to add `**/` at the beginning of the path as the add-on installed in user profile path

Comment: I had some problems with the paths of features and steps. The reason was that I was skipping the creation of a `.vscode/` folder mentioned in the extension docs. Just in case this can help someone like it did for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610271/7012085

Comment: How to create steps automatically?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! , i was facing same problem. Thanks for the Solution

Comment: i set up my feature files to be inside cypress/integration/, say cypress/integration/google.feature - having that js file would be in cypress/integration/google/google.js  and vscode setting for navigation is:  "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "cypress/integration/**/*.js",     
    ],

Comment: how do you detect nested steps in vscode? I have some steps being called inside other step definitions. Eg `And(/^I've a step inside the step definition$/) do
  step 'I am calling this step'
end`

Answer (score 2):

I have a cucumber with java project and following worked for me:

```
 "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "**/*Steps.java"
],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "**/*.feature"
```