# Navigating from Feature file to step defination: Any Plugins

Tags: javascript, selenium, visual-studio-code, webdriver-io, gherkin

In visual studio cod, How to navigate from feature to step definition. Do we need any additional plugins or any configuration needs to be added. I have downloaded the Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support plugin but still cannot navigate from .feature to the step definition.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of `Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support` plugin has the explanation for it.

You need to add the below in your settings:

```
{
"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "test/features/step_definitions/*.js",
    "node_modules/qa-lib/src/step_definitions/*.js"
],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "test/features/*feature",
"cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true
}
```

`cucumberautocomplete.steps` => provide the path of the step definitions.
`cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures` => provide the path of the feature files

After this(might be after a restart), `cmd + click`(on mac) would take to the step definition.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Thanks Naveen, In the setting.json I added the code but still it does not work

Comment: Could you please provide your `user settings` values: FYI this is what i have:
{
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "npm-intellisense.packageSubfoldersIntellisense": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "step-definitions/*.js",
        "step-definitions/*.ts"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*.feature"
}
Ignore the other settings. my vscode is `1.25.1` version

Answer (score 5):

Having installed the extension [`alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete), I tried modifying the settings from both the UI of the extension and its corresponding settings JSON (by default, mine were in `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`). But this didn't work because I got this error in the `*.feature` files: `Was unable to find step for "Some feature description"`.

I noticed I had skipped a step mentioned in the extension docs... By default, it was getting the `settings.json` from my userspace and not my work(project)space.

For me, the solution was to go to the root directory of my project (usually outside of `/src`, where you have the `package.json` and `node_modules/`) and create a `.vscode/` folder. Then, create a `settings.json` file and paste there the `cucumberautocomplete` configuration with the paths **relative** to this brand new file.

Below I show a schema:

```
myProject/
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── subdir1
│   ├── src
│   └── test
│       └── e2e
│           └── src
│               ├── features
│               │   └── myfeature1.feature
│               ├── mypageobject1.po.ts
│               └── steps
│                   └── mystep1.step.ts
└── .vscode
    └── settings.json
```

An example of configuration would be:

```
{
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "subidr1/test/e2e/src/steps/*.steps.ts"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "subidr1/test/e2e/src/feature/*.feature"
}
```

Note that you could use `**/*.steps.ts` and `**/*.feature` paths but every time the extension settings file changes, when you `Ctr + Click` on a feature description, you will need to wait for the editor to resolve the paths. Otherwise, there is no waiting time.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me and should be accepted as the correct answer.